# How to get current active live streams from a channel?

Tags: youtube-api

I want to get a list of active streams from the channel. I am trying to do this through the following query. But he shows a stream that ended a day ago. Maybe someone has a working solution?

```
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=CHANNEL_ID&part=snippet&key=API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.
I used this link instead:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=CHANNEL_ID&eventType=live&type=video&key=API_KEY
```